How to remove this invisible character from string
Below is the string, and the invisible character sits between the space and 'Co', which returns ascii value 63 and Unicode value 8206.
'X ‎Co'
Tried replace(@string, unicode(8206), ''), replace(@string, ascii(63), ''), both failed to work.
Much appreciated if anyone can share the light here.

The UNICODE( nchar ) function returns the int code-point of a single character - and 8206 is not an nchar - I think you want NCHAR(63) instead.

Whar is the type of @string?

It's nvarchar(255), tried NCHAR(63), no luck

That should be the space ahead.

If you use an nvarchar Literal, @DaleK , you should see 32 followed by 8206: db<>fiddle

Unicode 8206 is a Left to Right Marker (LRM), and many control characters do not play nice with non-binary collations.
You'll likely need to COLLATE the string to a binary collation and then back to the database default:
SELECT REPLACE(N'X ‎Co' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2,NCHAR(8206),'') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

